# Get HTTPResponse data on current page, instead of opening new one to view it

Tags: javascript, python, html, http, shopify

I'm fairly new to web dev, and web services in general, but have more extensive programming experience in some other areas. 
Anyways, I have some Python Code which is called by a shopify form with method=GET.

I take in that info, and do some things to it in my script and then at the end of my function I do

```
return HttpResponse(text[0][2], content_type="text/plain")
```

This causes the original shopify page to redirect to a new page which just shows the message in text[0][2]. What i need, is to be able to put text[0][2] on the Shopify page I have the form on. Is this possible?

Comment: Using javascript ajax you can request to your host with python response

Comment: I tried that after this, and I think Shopify is blocking me from changing the page :( I decided to create an entirely separate landing page

Comment: have you used ajax cross domain ?